# Can someone help me to find out why i get an 500 error in this code I am a beginner

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting an HTTP error 500, produced by the code below:

```
else if ($_POST['submit'] == "button2") {
    $tbVraag = $_POST['tbVraag'];
    $tbText = $_POST['tbText'];
    $tbQuestId = $_POST['tbQuestId'];


    $UpdateQuest = "UPDATE Vragen SET Title=:Title, `Text`=:txt WHERE QuestionId=:QuestionId";
    $stmt = $dbQuiz->prepare($UpdateQuest);

    $stmt->bindparam(':Title', $tbVraag);
    $stmt->bindparam(':txt', $tbText);
    $stmt->bindparam(':QuestionId', $tbQuestId);
    $stmt->execute();

    $tbAnt1 = $_POST['tbAnt1'];

    $UpdateAnt = "UPDATE Antwoorden SET `Text`=:antTxt WHERE AnswerId= ?";
    $statement = $dbQuiz->prepare($UpdateAnt);

    $statement->bindparam(':antTxt,', $tbAnt1);
    $statement->execute();

    echo "Update successfully completed!";

}
```

I have the suspicion that the error is caused by the second question in the code. Here is the error message I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional
>   parameters' in
>   /home/lab/domains/u-approachlab.nl/public_html/blendi/Website/opslaan.php:81
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/lab/domains/u-approachlab.nl/public_html/blendi/Website/opslaan.php(81):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Yes only a 500 error nothing more :(

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). That way you can get some error messages which can tell you more about the error.

Comment: you are binding your params differently

Comment: see this on how to bind params using POD http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Oke i got this error right know: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters' in /home/lab/domains/u-approachlab.nl/public_html/blendi/Website/opslaan.php:81 Stack trace: #0 /home/lab/domains/u-approachlab.nl/public_html/blendi/Website/opslaan.php(81): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your question mark in the second query:

```
$UpdateAnt = "UPDATE Antwoorden SET `Text`=:antTxt WHERE AnswerId= ?";
$statement = $dbQuiz->prepare($UpdateAnt);

$statement->bindparam(':antTxt,', $tbAnt1);
$statement->execute();
```

You add a question mark, but you never bind it as a parameter.

You should use something like this:

```
$UpdateAnt = "UPDATE Antwoorden SET `Text`=:antTxt WHERE AnswerId= :answerId";
```

And then also add it as a parameter:

```
$statement->bindparam(':answerId,', $answerId);
```

I don't see any `answerId` in your code though, so you need to get that somehow.